# does python has its error report message like $! in perl

Tags: python, perl

I am wondering if python has its error report message equivalent to $! in perl ?
Anyone who could give me an answer will be greatly appreciated.

Added:

```
example% ./test
File "./test", line 7
  test1 = test.Test(dir)
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When Exception occurs, I got something like this. If I apply try and catch block,
I can catch it and use sys.exit(**message**) to log the message. But, is there any chance
that I can get the string **SyntaxError: invalid syntax** and put it in **message**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, since I've never done any perl coding. But [python's logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) might be of interest to you

Comment: For those curious: Here are the docs on `$!`: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables

Comment: perl has die() function where you can put $! to get error message from the system

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, my initial problem to Keith's solution was that my python version is 2.4.4 so it does not support except ...as... Now, the problem is solved by updating my python to 2.6.

Comment: @rainzwr, `$!` is not set by `die()` or `eval`. Your thinking of `$@` (a.k.a `$EVAL_ERROR`) which is set by `eval` to the parameter passed to `die()`. `$!` (a.k.a. `$OS_ERROR`) mimics the behavior of C's `errno` global, which is set to an error code when a system call fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python generally uses exceptions to report errors. If some OS operation returns an error code, it raises an exception that you catch in a try-except block. For OS operations, that is OSError. The errno is contained in the exception instance.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

try:
        os.stat("xxx")
except OSError as err:
        print (err)
        # The "err" object is on instance of OSError. It supports indexing, with the first element as the errno value.
        print(err[0])
```

Output:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxx'
2
```

Comment: err is NOT a tuple. It's an instance of OSError class which, as most exception classes, supports indexing.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct equivalent, as far as I'm aware.

Python tends to favour throwing exceptions instead, which lets you access the error message afterwards in a similar manner, albeit through the exception object instead of a special variable.